# Can`t receive GRPC stream

Tags: python-2.7, iterator, grpc

I am trying to receive stream from some GRPC server, code of which is not accessible to me.

Here is the code of my GRPC client:

```
class Client():
    def __init__ (self, grpcIP, grpcPort, params):
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel('%s:%d' % (grpcIP, grpcPort))
        grpc.channel_ready_future(self.channel).result()
        self.stub = pb2_grpc.DataCloneStub(self.channel)
        self.params = params
        self.host = grpcIP
    def StartSender(self):
        params = pb2.StartParameters(**self.params)
        try:
            res = self.stub.Start(params)
            print(type(res))
            for pr in res:
                print(pr.current_progress)
        except grpc.RpcError as e:
            print(e)
```

Here are snippets from proto file that is used.
Method:

```
rpc Start (StartParameters) returns (stream Progress) {}
```

Message in stream:

```
    message Progress {
      double current_progress = 1;
      uint64 total_sent = 2;
      uint64 total_size = 3;
      string file_name = 4;
      Error error = 5;
   }
```

As I understand self.stub.Start(params) should return iterator with objects of type Progress. The problem is that it returns something with type grpc._channel._Rendezvous. I can`t iterate through the response. It doesn`t catch any exceptions either.

Did someone experience such behavior? Is it possible that issue comes not from client side?

Answer (score 0):

Class `grpc._channel._Rendezvous` is also an iterator, you can check the streaming RPC example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_client.py#L96).

The code you posted is correct implementation. If the program blocked at the `for pr in res` line, it is possible that the server is not sending any response (or taking a long time), hence the client side is blocked.